# Observer for sever messages over a SSL socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, observers

I have a Java client that connects to a server via a SSL socket. I can successfully connect and send messages to the server.

The server sends messages to all connected clients about various events (like when a client connects/disconnects).

How do I attach an event listener (observer) to my socket that will get notified when a message is sent by the server?

*I **think** this (or a similar question) was answered here on SO, specifically recommending the observer pattern, with code samples, but I neglected to bookmark it and I can't seem to be able to find it again.*

Comment: Here you go. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942204/observer-pattern-used-with-java-socket-programing-not-working

Comment: Nope, it's not that one. Thanks anyway.